# Keys in python dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, hash

The problem that I am having is distributed over many source files and my attempts to reproduce the problem in a simple linear format have failed. Nonetheless the problem I am having is simply described.

I have a class `Path` for which I implement `__hash__` and `__eq__`

I have an item of type `Path` in a `dict` as evidenced by

```
path in list(thedict)
>> True
```

I verify that `path == other` and `hash(path) == hash(other)` and `id(path) == id(other)` where `other` is an item taken straight out of `list(thedict.keys())`. Yet, I get the following

```
path in thedict:
>> False
```

and attempting the following results in a `KeyError`

```
thedict[path]
```

So my question is, under what circumstance is this possible? I would have expected that if the `path` is in `list(thedict)` then it must be in `thedict.keys()` and hence we must be able to write `thedict[path]`. What is wrong with this assumption?

### Further Info

If it helps, the classes in question are listed below. It is at the level of `SpecificationPath` that the above issue is observed

```
class Path:
    pass

@dataclass
class ConfigurationPath(Path):
    configurationName: str = None
    
    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return self.configurationName

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.configurationName)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, ConfigurationPath):
            return False
        return self.configurationName == other.configurationName

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

@dataclass
class SpecificationPath(Path):
    configurationPath: ConfigurationPath
    specificationName: str = None
    
    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.configurationPath}.{self.specificationName or ''}"

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.configurationPath, self.specificationName))
    
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, SpecificationPath):
            return False
        if self.configurationPath != other.configurationPath:
            return False
        if self.specificationName != other.specificationName:
            return False
        return True
```

In response to a comment below, here is the output in the (Spyder) debug terminal, where `pf` is an object containing the `paths` dictionary using paths as keys and the object in question (`self`) has the path.

```
In : others = list(pf.paths.keys())
In : other = others[1]
In : self.path is other
Out[1]: True
In : self.path in pf.paths
Out[1]: False
```

Comment: Can you provide your implementation for `__eq__` and `__hash__`?

Comment: Is Path mutable?

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon could cause a problem. But in the OPs testing, as long as there is no mutation between testing that `path == other` and `hash(path) == hash(other) and `id(path) == id(other)` and then testing `path in thedict` then it is quite surprising.

Comment: So, what type is giving you the problem? Can you show us the outputs of your debugging/exploration?

Comment: Thanks everyone. I have added more info as requested

Comment: I just tested the code you provided with: `aPath = SpecificationPath('a', 'b'); aPath2 = SpecificationPath('a', 'b'); thedict = {aPath: 'some_val'};` and `aPath2 in thedict` returns True. Can you give a small and replicable example of what is going wrong?

Comment: Minor nitpick: When your `isinstance` check fails, you should be returning `NotImplemented`, not `False`; that will allow the right-side class (if it's not the same as the left) to attempt the comparison (if both return `NotImplemented`, Python converts that to `False` for you).

Comment: Similarly my test code fails to find any error; the classes are able to be used as keys in dictionaries as expected. There is a lot going on in the main application but I'm hoping that understanding why my assumption as stated is broken (which it must be for this error to occur) will lead to the source of the issue.

Comment: Thanks @ShadowRanger I didn't realize that was the case. Will change it!

Comment: @Mark Your assumption does not appear to be wrong when referring to native dictionaries. If you'll forgive me making a guess. Could pf.paths perhaps be a custom class (not a simple native dictionary object)?

Comment: @tdelaney not really since I have several items in that dictionary. These are not class variables as I am using the dataclass mechanism, which converts them to instance variables

Comment: @tdelaney: What class variable? These are dataclasses; the annotations at class level are used to make a `__init__` that actually sets instance variables.

Comment: @ShadowRanger - Oh, right.

Comment: Side-note: Is there a reason you're manually implementing `__eq__` and `__hash__`? `@dataclass` would generate the `__eq__` for you with no changes; make it `@dataclass(frozen=True)` would generate the `__hash__` for you too (`@dataclass(unsafe_hash=True)` would do it too, but leave your instances mutable, which hashable instances should not be).

Comment: @ShadowRanger I hadn't a particular reason (I hadn't thought of this) but I can think of one now. The paths do want to be mutable as I am setting specificationName to None in places (leaving them Anonymous to be filled out later). Further, it is on an instance where the specificationName is None that this occurs, however in my simple test scripts I can get away with setting this to None without an error. Could mutability of the hashable instances cause an error such as this?

Comment: "The paths do want to be mutable" - then they shouldn't be hashable. Mutation breaks hashes.

Comment: @Mark: That would absolutely cause a problem. Writing answer now.

Comment: (We could have told you this 26 minutes ago if you'd answered Brian McCutchon's question. We probably could have just told you anyway, but no one did.)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica ah yes you're right. I missed that little comment, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65245354/keys-in-python-dictionaries/65245599#comment115347833_65245354):

> The paths do want to be mutable as I am setting `specificationName` to `None` in places (leaving them Anonymous to be filled out later). Further, it is on an instance where the `specificationName` is `None` that this occurs, however in my simple test scripts I can get away with setting this to None without an error. Could mutability of the hashable instances cause an error such as this?

There's your problem. You're putting these objects in a `dict` immediately after creation, while `specificationName` is `None`, so it's stored in the `dict` with a hashcode based on `None` (that hashcode is cached in the `dict` itself, and using that hashcode is the only way to look up the object in the future). If you subsequently change it to *anything* that produces a different hash value (read almost everything else), the object is stored in a bucket corresponding to the old hash code, but using it for lookups computes the new hash code and cannot find that bucket.

If `specificationName` must be mutable, then it cannot be part of the hash, it's as simple as that. This will potentially increase collisions, but it can't be helped; a mutable field can't be part of the hash without triggering this exact problem.

Comment: Also, avoid implementing your own `__hash__` and `__eq__`. Let `dataclass` do it for you. There are so many pitfalls...

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon: The OP got those mostly right (aside from not using `NotImplemented` correctly). But yeah, it's much better to let `dataclass` do it for you. Although they don't recommend it, they do note that you could even omit specific fields from the generated hash by initializing the attribute definition to a `field(hash=False)` (might require you to use `@dataclass(unsafe_hash=True)` instead of `@dataclass(frozen=True)` to support the OP's case of a mutable field that shouldn't be part of the hash), which would allow `dataclass` to generate `__hash__` w/o use of `specificationName`.

Comment: In case anyone wants it, here's a minimum example of this in action: https://gist.github.com/Multihuntr/7756efa077b7837e494098adf0053dac